# cannot declare field ‘’ to be of abstract type ‘’

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm trying to write asynchronous code on callbacks and stuck into this error:

```
error: cannot declare field ‘std::_Head_base<3, Callback, false>::_M_head_impl’ to be of abstract type ‘Callback’ 
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Callback’
...
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::tuple<api_add(int, int, Callback&&)::<lambda(int, int, Callback&&)>, int, int, Callback>::tuple(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)} };
```

My abstract class:

```
class Callback {
public:
    virtual void OnResult(ApiResultType res) = 0;
};
```

Derived class:

```
class ApiCallBack: public Callback {
public:
    ApiCallBack() {

    };
    virtual void OnResult(ApiResultType res) {
        std::cout << "OnResult: " << res.first << "; " << res.second << std::endl;
        ...
    }
};
```

main():

```
int main() {
    // Running API operations

    ApiCallBack Callable;
    api_add(kOperationArg1, kOperationArg2, std::forward<ApiCallBack>(Callable));
    ...
}
```

Asynchronous function implementation:

```
void api_add(int arg1, int arg2, Callback &&func) {
    std::async(std::launch::async, [](int arg1, int arg2, Callback &&func) {
                func.OnResult({"API_Mul", arg1 + arg2});
               }, arg1, arg2, std::forward<Callback>(func));
}
```

After spending a bit of time understanding the code I wrote I suggest that the error is in the last chunk of code (***async*** or ***lambda***), but can't still figure out what's actually wrong. Please help.

Comment: simply remove `virtual` keyword in `ApiCallBack` and it should complie.

Comment: @ceorron, unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @ceorron -- that shouldn't matter; it's okay to mark an overriding function as `virtual`, although it isn't necessary.

Comment: The `virtual` is unnecessary, but should not result in a compiler error, and particularly not this reported error. I recommend backing up your code and hacking out a [mre]. If making the MRE doesn't reduce the noise around the error enough for you to spot and fix the cause, add the MRE to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem with your code is this:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, [](int arg1, int arg2, Callback &&func) {
        func.OnResult({"API_Mul", arg1 + arg2});
}, arg1, arg2, std::forward<Callback>(func));
```

The call to async that you are using has this signature:

```
template< class Function, class... Args>
std::future<std::invoke_result_t<std::decay_t<Function>, std::decay_t<Args>...>>
async( std::launch policy, Function&& f, Args&&... args);
```

The important thing to notice above is the returned future holds an invoke_result_t containing `std::decay_t<Args>...`, which removes references (and constness, decays arrays and functions to pointer, etc).  But removing reference is the problem you're running into, as it would try to invoke your function with those args.

Since you are passing a `Callback&` to the function, after decay it is `Callback`, and the instantiated template code attempts to hold just a Callback (base) by value.

The real fix here, if you want to keep your original approach (for the most part) is to use a std::reference_wrapper to hold your callback.  This can be done with a call to std::ref() -- which returns a reference wrapper referencing its argument.  Decaying a reference wrapper does not lose its "reference semantics":

```
std::async(std::launch::async, [](int arg1, int arg2, Callback &&func) {
        func.OnResult({"API_Mul", arg1 + arg2});
}, arg1, arg2, std::ref(func)); // <<<<< HERE
```

Of course, it's also your responsibility to ensure that the callback actually lives as long as the async code can run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `override` for overriding functions.

```
// virtual void OnResult(ApiResultType res) { -->
void OnResult(ApiResultType res) override {
  // ...
```

`std::forward<ApiCallBack>(Callable))` makes no sense, since Callable is not a rvalue or generic reference. Use `std::move(Callable))`.

The above will not fix the error, but will make the code a bit better. The solution:

```
int main() {
    // Running API operations

    std::unique_ptr<Callback> Callable(new ApiCallBack);
    api_add(kOperationArg1, kOperationArg2, std::move(Callable));
    ...
}

void api_add(int arg1, int arg2, std::unique_ptr<Callback> func) {
    std::async(std::launch::async, [](int arg1, int arg2, std::unique_ptr<Callback> func) {
                func->OnResult({"API_Mul", arg1 + arg2});
               }, arg1, arg2, std::move(func));
}
```

The better approach is using `std::function<void(ApiResultType)>` instead of the Callback or unique pointer.

```
class ApiCallBack {
public:
    void operator()(ApiResultType res) {
        std::cout << "OnResult: " << res.first << "; " << res.second << std::endl;
        ...
    }
};

int main() {
    // Running API operations

    ApiCallback Callable;
    api_add(kOperationArg1, kOperationArg2, std::move(Callable));
    ...
}

void api_add(int arg1, int arg2,  std::function<void(ApiResultType)> func) {
    std::async(std::launch::async, [](int arg1, int arg2, std::function<void(ApiResultType)> func) {
                func({"API_Mul", arg1 + arg2});
               }, arg1, arg2, std::move(func));
}
```

Comment: `override` is irrelevant here. You may have a style preference for it, but many people don't.

Comment: This "solution" can't work. `std::unique_ptr<Callback>` cannot be passed to a function that expects a `Callback&&`, with or without calling `std::move`. Changing to `std::function` adds overhead that isn't needed in this case, and there's no reason to think that it would fix the problem.